# use a css stylesheet on a jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I am making a website using html, css, flask and jinja2.

I have a page working on a flask server, the buttons and labels etc. are displayed, but the css stylesheet I have is not loaded in.

How would I link a stylesheet to a jinja2 template. I have looked around on the internet but cannot find out how.

Here is the css stylesheet link; should I change this, or the python code?

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`

here is my flask code:

```
@app.route('/')
def resultstemplate():
    return render_template('questions.html', head='Welcome!')
```

here are the locations of the files:

`/python-code.py
 /templates/template.html
 /templates/styles.css`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

All public files (the ones that are not processed, like templates or python files) should be placed into dedicated static folders. By default, Jinja2 has one static folder called `static`.

This should fix your problem:

1. Move `/templates/styles.css` to `/static/styles.css`
2. Update your code with following code, that will be translated into correct file location:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
   ```

More info on static files in Jinja2 is [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files).

Comment: yes, it sort-of works. The font style and size (and maybe others but I can't tell) have worked but nothing else, so the page is not fully working.

Comment: If I have correctly understood you, CSS is loaded and works, which was covered in this question/answer. If you have other issues, accept this answer, and post them in separate questions.

Comment: yes it works perfectly, sorry, it was looking weird as I made it with Chrome, and was now viewing it firefox; there is now incompatibility.

Comment: If you are still having issues with the styling not loading after using the above code, try either clearing the cache of your browser or a 'hard refresh' by pressing `ctrl+shift+r`.

Answer (score 6):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

href value must be within quotes.

make sure the file name and path are proper 
OR try the below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}"/>
```

Comment: yes you are right my code is wrong, but that doesn't make it work; I think the path is right; I have now posted the paths on the question

Answer (score 2):

The order of handler might cause the problems:

```
url: /stylesheets static_dir: stylesheets
url: /.* script: helloworld.application
```

will work instead of

```
url: /.* script: helloworld.application
url: /stylesheets static_dir: stylesheets
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use the super() block style .
see the code below:

```
{% block style %}

{{ super() }}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}"/>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried almost every solution on Stack Overflow. It only worked for me when I placed the `static` folder in the **same** directory as my `run.py` file.
I changed my folder structure from:

```
app/
    views
    static
    templates
run.py
```

To:

```
app/
    views
    templates
static
run.py
```

I guess moving the `run.py` instead would work too. Have a look at this [Jinja Templating Tutorial](http://www.compjour.org/lessons/flask-recalls/intro-to-jinja2-templating/#moving-out-into-staticstylescss) for extra info. Not sure why I had to change the structure for it to work though.

Comment: Here is a solution that works that allows you to avoid refactoring

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961132/flask-cant-find-static-folder-when-i-have-set-a-new-root-path

Answer (score 0):

To add to what's been said here, be sure to update Jinja2 to v2.10, as lesser versions seem to cause this same bug. Cheers!