# Why won't my Flask app connect to my CSS files?

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Here is my project hierarchy:

Project

[image]

Here is my HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='custom.css') }}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

My .py flask file :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, json, url_for, request, abort
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.web_zoo

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my CSS file :

```
body {
    color: green;
}
h1 {
    color: orange;
}
```

The HTML and .py files work fine and the HTML is rendered and displayed on the page. However the CSS doesn't change. It just displays it in normal black text.

**NOTE** : All those imports are there as I was doing something else. I stripped off everything else and still have this problem.

I can link bootstrap to it, and the CSS works, but not for my own CSS files.

I have looked at and tried these following solutions :

[CSS Problems with Flask Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772884/css-problems-with-flask-web-app)

[Application not picking up .css file (flask/python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259847/application-not-picking-up-css-file-flask-python)

[best way to override bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/best-way-to-override-bootstrap-css)

It's probably quite obvious but I'm stuck. Any help? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** - I have added a picture of the project hierarchy now instead of just a list. As you can see there are some other HTML files in there too, but none are used nor referenced.

Comment: Are you sure that tag <link> gets a correct path to your css file?

Comment: Inspect the rendered HTML Code to see the result of `url_for`

Comment: Have you tried to go to url where your css files and hit F5? e.g. go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/custom.css (with your browser) and hit F5. For me that did the job.

Comment: @reporter 99% sure yes - I have edited a photo in now.

Comment: @Moyote THAT WORKED BUT WHY?!

Comment: @A.Lord I don't remeber actually (it was a while ago when i had this issue), but here's an interesting thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714653/flask-css-not-updating.

Comment: @A.Lord do you want to give me +1 from solution?

Comment: @A.Lord https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263096/css-file-is-not-refreshing-in-my-browser Also this seems to be related to this issue

Comment: Google Chrome stores styles in its own cache. If you make changes to the CSS and try to access the same webpage, the last saved CSS is retained. You have to go directly to the CSS File (accessed over HTTP) and refresh for the changes to be reflected

Comment: You shouldn't also need to use `url_for` for linking stylesheets. Relative links works just as fine :P

Comment: Wrote up an alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034812/use-a-css-stylesheet-on-a-jinja2-template/54026518#54026518

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

in Chrome to reload the CSS.

On Mac try:

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

> Otherwise **right-click** on the page in Chrome, select **Inspect** and select the **Console** tab to see what errors you get.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Much easier than having to refresh the CSS file each time.