# GridLayout not putting rows properly

Tags: css, flask, css-grid

I am quite new to `css`, so for a quick project of mine I needed a `gridlayout` and came up with this hotch-potch of `css`:

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: [row1start] 20% [row2start] 20% [row3start] 10% [row4start] 50% auto [last_col];
    grid-template-columns: [column_one_start] 50% [column_two_start] 50% auto [end];
    justify-items: stretch;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.container.row1 {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    grid-column-start: column_one_start;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: row1start;
    grid-row-end: span 1;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.container.row2 {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    grid-column-start: column_one_start;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: row2start;
    grid-row-end: span 1;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.container.row3 {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    grid-column-start: column_one_start;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: methodology_row_start;
    grid-row-end: span 1;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.container.row4 {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    grid-column-start: column_one_start;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: row4start;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

Essentially, all I want to do is to have `4` rows (`tracks`, in `css` terminology), each resp. occupying `20,20,10,50` percent of the space.
Here is my `html`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Template</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/container.css') }}">
 </head>

 <body>
     <header>
        <h1 class="logo">Template with grid</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row1">
            <p>Row 1</p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
            Esse aliquid laboriosam minima ex praesentium recusandae
            reprehenderit unde sit tempore atque aut commodi quae expedita
            corrupti, dignissimos architecto. Eius, maiores ad?
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <p>Row 2</p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
            Esse aliquid laboriosam minima ex praesentium recusandae
            reprehenderit unde sit tempore atque aut commodi quae expedita
            corrupti, dignissimos architecto. Eius, maiores ad?
        </div>
        <div class="row3">
            <p>Row 3</p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
            Esse aliquid laboriosam minima ex praesentium recusandae
            reprehenderit unde sit tempore atque aut commodi quae expedita
            corrupti, dignissimos architecto. Eius, maiores ad?
        </div>
        <div class="row4">
            <p>Row 4</p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
            Esse aliquid laboriosam minima ex praesentium recusandae
            reprehenderit unde sit tempore atque aut commodi quae expedita
            corrupti, dignissimos architecto. Eius, maiores ad?
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I would like to get this to look as I want:

[image]

Right now `Row 2` is wandering somewhere in column `2`, for example.
I want them all nicely occupy their respective spaces, with empty space left,
if necessary, in their respective compartments (if a row is not filled fully,
let it be padded with blanks).

EDIT: Hey, I am sorry, I just opened this in Opera just by clicking, and it seems to work. Looks like my `Flask` app's `render_template()` is screwing things up. And I am calling it with just something like:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("template02.html")
```

So, why is `render_template()` not honoring my layout?

Comment: Like this you mean - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pMRmaQ

Comment: Yes, but it still shows the same with `Flask`'s `render_template()`

Comment: Good resource to clear any doubt about Grid Layout  [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: @DhanukaPerera, this is actually what I used ))

Comment: @Paulie_D, +1 -- didn't know (obviously) that `css` supports regex.

Answer (score 0):

The last answer here: [use a css stylesheet on a jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034812/use-a-css-stylesheet-on-a-jinja2-template) helped.
I don't know why one has to change the folder structure for that to work.