# Flask can't find static folder when I have set a new root_path

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app that sets a custom `root_path`.

```
app = Flask(
    __name__,
    root_path='flask_news'
)

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Flask can serve `flask_news/templates/login.html` but will not find the required CSS, which is under `flask_news/static/bulma.css`

In my template file I'm asking for the CSS like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='bulma.css')}}">
```

and the head of the served webpage looks like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='bulma.css')}}">
```

Why is Flask not able to serve the required CSS? I think I need to change something in how the `static` folder is located but I'm not sure on how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you can try specifying the `static` directory as well as the `templates` directory locations when initializing your application, something along the lines of:

```
app = Flask(__name__, 
            static_folder='./flask_news/static',
            template_folder='./flask_news/templates')
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This helped, setting **both** the template folder and the static folder did the thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the static folder to be whatever you'd like, as in this case you can set it up to './flask_news/static/'

To do so, when you initialize your Flask object, pass in the path to the static_folder parameter:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='./flask_news/static')
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't do it. And I have checked that the static folder is present in that location. Is there a way to debug this? or keep setting the static folder untill it hits?