# Jinja2 Email Template

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Using Jijna2, I'm trying to make a responsive `HTML` email template which is almost simple

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <p><strong>Hello</strong>,</p>
    <p>Below are the deals running on <a href="https://www.{{ url }}.com">{{ url }}</a> at <strong>{{ date }}</strong>:</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
    <ul>
        {% for image in images %}
          <a href="{{ image }}">
            <img src="{{ image }}" width=500" height="200">
          </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <p><strong>Regards,</strong></p>
    <p>Team</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's what is shown currently:

[image]

and during full screen:

[image]

How to make it responsive in this case and keep the display of images one by one. not side by side during full screen or mobile screen!

Comment: Surrounding images with list items as `<li style="width:100%">` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't consider this responsive but to keep images one on top of each other, you can try to just have them as list items and hide the list bullets with `list-style: none`, like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <p><strong>Hello</strong>,</p>
    <p>Below are the deals running on <a href="https://www.{{ url }}.com">{{ url }}</a> at <strong>{{ date }}</strong>:</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
    <ul style="list-style: none">
      <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200" width=500" height="200">
          </a>
    <li/>
    <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200" width=500" height="200">
          </a>
    <li/>
    </ul>
    <p><strong>Regards,</strong></p>
    <p>Team</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or as I told you in comments, make the anchor link to have full width like: `<a href="{{ image }}" style="width:100%">`

Answer (score 1):

Good morning Ahmed, what you can do is insert the css code you need to behave responsively, as in the example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    table,
    td,
    tr {
        vertical-align: top;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    * {
        line-height: inherit;
    }

    a[x-apple-data-detectors=true] {
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
</style>
<style id="media-query" type="text/css">
    @media (max-width: 520px) {

        .block-grid,
        .col {
            min-width: 320px !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
            display: block !important;
        }
```

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/25036606/7658985 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a class on the image container `li` and then make that class have a width of 100% using css

So in your case:

```
<style>
.full-width{
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <p><strong>Hello</strong>,</p>
    <p>Below are the deals running on <a href="https://www.{{ url }}.com">{{ url }}</a> at <strong>{{ date }}</strong>:</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
    <ul>
        {% for image in images %}
          <li class="full-width">
          <a href="{{ image }}">
            <img src="{{ image }}" height="200">
          </a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <p><strong>Regards,</strong></p>
    <p>Team</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Should do the trick.